# Jooq to use existing connection for fetchOne or execute

Tags: java, jdbc, playframework-2.0, jooq

I tried to manage the connection on my own within the play framework, and implements the jooq Connection provider as:

```
public class PlayConnectionProvider implements ConnectionProvider {

  private Connection connection = null;

  @Override
  public Connection acquire() throws DataAccessException {
    if (connection == null) {
      connection = DB.getConnection();
    }
    return connection;
  }

  @Override
  public void release(Connection released) throws DataAccessException {
    if (this.connection != released) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected " + this.connection + " but got " + released);
    }
    try {
      if (connection.getAutoCommit() == true) {
        connection.close();
        connection = null;
      }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      Logger.error("Error closing connection " + connection, e);
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I call execute(), it seems jooq will always call the acquire() and create a new connection instead of using the existing one. I found the new connection is obtained by DefaultExecuteContext in the execute() function:

```
public final Connection connection() {
    ConnectionProvider provider = this.connectionProvider != null?this.connectionProvider:this.configuration.connectionProvider();
    if(this.connection == null && provider != null) {
        this.connection(provider, provider.acquire());
    }

    return this.connection;
}
```

Is there any way to configure the connection for execute()?

Comment: Are you sure you're not resetting the connection to `null` yourself in `release()`? What jOOQ version are you using? And just to be sure: How are you creating your `ConnectionProvider`?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, jOOQ always calls [`acquire()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ConnectionProvider.html#acquire--) at the beginning of each `execute()` call. But it also calls [`release()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ConnectionProvider.html#release-java.sql.Connection-) at the end of it, and you seem to be resetting your cached connection yourself

```
if (connection.getAutoCommit() == true) {
    connection.close();
    connection = null;
}
```

... because Play's `DB.getConnection()` returns a connection with auto-commit turned on

- https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/java/play/db/DB.html#getConnection()

#### A note on thread safety

Note that if you're caching the connection this way, `ConnectionProvider` will no longer be thread safe, and thus all objects containing it will not be thread safe either (including [`Configuration` and `DSLContext`](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/)). One way to maintain this thread safety would be to store the connection in a `ThreadLocal` inside your `ConnectionProvider`

Comment: Thanks Lukas. I finally get one solution, which uses 
DSL.using(connection, SQLDialect.MYSQL) when I want to manage the transaction myself, or uses DSL.using(defaultConnectionProvider, SQLDialect.MYSQL) when I'd like jooq's create to automatically acquire() or realease() connections. As long as the transaction is small within one function, play should be OK with its commit or rollback behavior.